# changing variable of another component

Tags: angular

home.component.html

```html
<p> its the home component </p>

<app-step1 *ngIf="step1"></app-step1>
<app-step2 *ngIf="step2"></app-step2>
<app-step3 *ngIf="step3"></app-step3>
```

home.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  step1:boolean = false;
  step2:boolean = false;
  step3:boolean = false;

  constructor(public router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.router.url.includes('step1')) {
      this.step1 = true;
    }
    else if(this.router.url.includes('step2')) {
      this.step2 = true;
    }
    else if(this.router.url.includes('step3')) {
      this.step3 = true;
    }
  }

}
```

step1.component.html

```html
<p>step 1 component is here!</p>
<button (click)="nextStep()">Next Step</button>
```

step1.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-step1',
  templateUrl: './step1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./step1.component.css']
})
export class Step1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  nextStep() {
    // in here step1 should be false, step2 should be true on the home.component.ts
  }

}
```

step2.component.html

```html
<p>step 2 component is here!</p>
<button (click)="nextStep()">Next Step</button>
```

step2.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-step2',
  templateUrl: './step2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./step2.component.css']
})
export class Step2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  nextStep() {
    // in here step2 should be false, step3 should be true on the home.component.ts
  }

}
```

step3.component.html

```html
<p>Finish</p>
```

I'm making wizards with components. I have to change variable of components in my function.

On these codes, I want to change step1, step2, step3 variables in the `nextStep()` function. I described on the function with a comment line what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should take look at `@Input` decorator in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs). You can create a variable with a `@Input` decorator on every step component and set any value.

Comment: I reviewed it, but i could not manage my codes. Angular's documentation is very complicated for beginners